# "of" vs. "from" in introductions with company affiliations

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, american-english

A person who owns a business called BBB Cupcakes is making a tutorial video for a for-fee e-learning platform. The hour-long video is purely a cupcake making lesson; it's not directly an advertisement for BBB Cupcakes. The person wants to quickly introduce herself at the beginning of the video. If "Hi, I'm AAA, owner of BBB Cupcakes," can't be used, which of the following is correct?

1. "Hi, I'm AAA from BBB Cupcakes."
2. "Hi, I'm AAA of BBB Cupcakes."

Comment: Both prepositions are fine, and I doubt there would be any kind of consensus on whether or not they potentially have slightly different *nuances* (and if so, exactly *what* those differences might be). But on average, ***from*** is more common - which imho is probably the *only* reason people might feel the need to come up with some subtle distinction applicable to contexts where a competent speaker chooses to use the less-favoured version.

Comment: Both are correct, but **from** is probably used more commonly, and (imo) **of** sounds more formal.

Comment: The following was said 8 years ago in a comment on Math.SE: "I don't think this is specific to English prepositions. People often complain about the arbitrariness of prepositions in languages they're learning until you point out to them the arbitrariness of prepositions in their native language." by @joriki

Comment: "Hi, I'm AAA **with** BBB Cupcakes."